# cities, country and zip_code models fields and modelsforms with django-cities

Tags: django

I'm trying to make three models fields `cities`, `country` and `zip_code` in my model so I can build a `ModelForm` and setup some custom signup, and for that I'm using [dajngo-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities#migration-configuration) library.

I've configured everything I need for the app in my project and I've done the migrations, so I have loaded `US` cities, countries and zip_codes in the system, but now I'm failing to understand how can I build this `model` fields so I can make `dropdown` select buttons in my forms, can someone please explain me how to build this properly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/). The example that they used in the docs is extremely similar to your use-case.

Here is a little hint -
You actually need to make 2 Models. This way you can have a [Many to One](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) database relation between City and Country models, which is exactly what you need.

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)    


class City(models.Model):
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: it was lame out of me to ask this question, with little effort I have done it, besides I've read django docs like million times, but nevertheless thaks

Comment: i have noticed its really easy to overlook stuff in the docs.